What is the best book to read Ramayana story in Malayalam?
What is the best book to read  Ramayana story in Malayalam?
What is the best book to read  Ramayana story in Kindle Malayalam?

Please read this article:
https://medium.com/@dharmastram/best-book-to-read-ramayanam-in-malayalam-8f1bc7e25fb4

Valmeeki Ramayanam-Sampoornam-Gadhyam (2 Volumes)
വാല്മീകിരാമായണം (ഗദ്യം, സമ്പൂർണ്ണം)- സി. ജി. വാര്യർ

Srimad Valmiki Ramayanam-Sampoornam-Gadhyam (2 Volumes)
Publisher: Sri Ramakrishna Math


Or there is one more version by DC books which is print on demand
